# Sticky Header in HTML code is not working

Tags: html, css, web

I have a problem with my HTML/CSS code. I just added a Navbar (only Desktop until now) and the "Sticky Navigation bar" isn't working.

Here the complete HTML code (CSS following):

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
}

/* Code by Vincent Photography */

.header {
    height: 720px;
    background-image: url(../images/header-background-edited.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 70% 30%;
}


/* Navigation */

.header {
    
}

.background-header {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(0.5rem);
    backdrop-filter: blur(0.5rem);
    top: 0; 
    position: sticky;
}

.header-navbar-links {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 30px;
    display: none;
    font-size: 18px;
}

@media (min-width: 750px) {
    .header-navbar-links {
        display: block;
    }
}

.header-navbar-links a {
    color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.header-navbar-links a:after {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
      bottom: 0;
      content: "";
      display: block;
      height: 2px;
      left: 50%;
      position: absolute;
      background: rgb(26,131,93);
      transition: width 0.3s ease 0s, left 0.3s ease 0s;
      width: 0;
    }
    .header-navbar-links a:hover:after { 
      width: 100%; 
      left: 0;
    }

.header-navbar-links a:hover {
    color: rgb(26,131,93);
}

.header-navbar-links li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 26px;
}

.header-logo {
    margin-top: 30px;
    float: left;
}

.header-logo-link {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: all 0.4s;
}

.header-logo-link:hover {
    color: rgb(26,131,93);
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ALPHA AUGMENTED SERVICES</title>

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="skeleton/skeleton.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="skeleton/normalize.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header">
        <div class="background-header">
            <div class="container">
                <nav class="header-navbar">
                    <div class="header-logo">
                        <a href="#" class="header-logo-link">Alpha</a>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="header-navbar-links">
                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="services.html">Our services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="about.html">About us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="slogan">
        <div class="slogan">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <br>
    <h1>
        Lorem Ipsum
    </h1>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </p>
    <br>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </p>
    <br>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </p>
    <br>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <h1>
        Lorem Ipsum
    </h1>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </p>
    <br>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </p>
    <br>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </p>
    <br>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <h1>
        Lorem Ipsum
    </h1>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </p>
    <br>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </p>
    <br>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </p>
    <br>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </p>
    <br>
    </div>
    <script defer src="js/app.jss"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

For you to know. I'm using the CSS tool Skeleton. For more information you can just visit this webpage: getskeleton.com

Comment: What is not working? Please explain some more. It looks like it is working just fine.

Comment: color: rgb(255, 255, 255); is white color, isnt it? Your font has that color on white background.

Comment: oh no! It should be white color, but your background doesnt have any height!

Answer (score 0):

you didnt set the height of the `.background-header`.

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
}

/* Code by Vincent Photography */

.header {
    height: 720px;
    background-image: url(../images/header-background-edited.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 70% 30%;
}


/* Navigation */

.header {
    
}

.background-header {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(0.5rem);
    backdrop-filter: blur(0.5rem);
    top: 0; 
    position: sticky;
    height: 100px;
}

.header-navbar-links {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 30px;
    display: none;
    font-size: 18px;
}

@media (min-width: 750px) {
    .header-navbar-links {
        display: block;
    }
}

.header-navbar-links a {
    color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.header-navbar-links a:after {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
      bottom: 0;
      content: "";
      display: block;
      height: 2px;
      left: 50%;
      position: absolute;
      background: rgb(26,131,93);
      transition: width 0.3s ease 0s, left 0.3s ease 0s;
      width: 0;
    }
    .header-navbar-links a:hover:after { 
      width: 100%; 
      left: 0;
    }

.header-navbar-links a:hover {
    color: rgb(26,131,93);
}

.header-navbar-links li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 26px;
}

.header-logo {
    margin-top: 30px;
    float: left;
}

.header-logo-link {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: all 0.4s;
}

.header-logo-link:hover {
    color: rgb(26,131,93);
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ALPHA AUGMENTED SERVICES</title>

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="skeleton/skeleton.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="skeleton/normalize.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header">
        <div class="background-header">
            <div class="container">
                <nav class="header-navbar">
                    <div class="header-logo">
                        <a href="#" class="header-logo-link">Alpha</a>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="header-navbar-links">
                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="services.html">Our services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="about.html">About us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="slogan">
        <div class="slogan">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <br>
    <h1>
        Lorem Ipsum
    </h1>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </p>
    <br>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </p>
    <br>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </p>
    <br>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <h1>
        Lorem Ipsum
    </h1>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </p>
    <br>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </p>
    <br>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </p>
    <br>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <h1>
        Lorem Ipsum
    </h1>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </p>
    <br>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </p>
    <br>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </p>
    <br>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </p>
    <br>
    </div>
    <script defer src="js/app.jss"></script>
</body>
</html>
```